# Which domain registrar offers the most complete API?

Tags: domain-registrar, api

I am looking for a domain registrar that offers an API that would allow changes like name servers to be made programmatically. GoDaddy do not seem to offer this, so I figured this might be a good forum to find out who does.

Comment: Have a look here first (if you have not done it already): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523260/recommendations-for-domain-name-registrar-with-api-support